# JPA Repository Name when uses Projections to select few fields

Tags: jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity class Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMP_MASTER")
public class Employee {

    private Integer employeeNumber;
    private String empFirstName;
    private String empSecondName;
    private int age;
    private String empAddress;

//constructor with fields ();
//getters and setters, equals and hascode , toString();
}
```

Then I have my JPARepo interface. To select employee id and employee Name I am using projections.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    public List<EmpIdAndEmpNameOnly> find(); // ? nothing is works here.

}

interface EmpIdAndEmpNameOnly {

    int getEmployeeNumber();

    String getEmpFirstName();
}
```

I am looking to get all the employee number and empfirstname. In this case what will be my repo method name ? tried findEmployee(), findEmployeeNumberAndEmpName(), nothing worked. Any one please help me to find out how this is working ? it gives big confusion all the time for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `findAllProjectedBy` or `findBy()` should be fine,

```
public List<EmpIdAndEmpNameOnly> findAllProjectedBy();
```

In the case of multiple projections,

```
List<Projection1> findBy(Projection1.class);
List<Projection2> findBy(Projection2.class);
List<Projection3> findBy(Projection2.class);
```

Check more details about dynamic projections [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic)

Comment: It gives compilation error in JPA repo interface. The return type is incompatible with JpaRepository<Employee,Integer>.findAll().

Comment: wow that worked Thanks . what if I have another projection interface in the same repo. In case if you can share some link it will be helpful.

Comment: I will accept the answer but I din't get clarity as multiple projections comes how to deal with it.

Comment: It won't compile as it won't qualify for Overload.

Comment: I don't have problem to accept the answer. But questions related to that is still exists. I wanted to see any one else can give some idea about that.

Comment: I got the solution. Updated the answer. I hope it helps.